# PHP: insert tag in DomDocument

Tags: php

I have the following html code :

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th >operatore</th>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
   <th >operatore</th>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
   <tr/>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to insert the following tags after the TABLE tag:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th >Nome IT</th>
        <th >a</th>
        <th >b</th>
        <th >c</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

so I'd like to get:

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th >Nome IT</th>
        <th >a</th>
        <th >b</th>
        <th >c</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
.....
```

I created the following code for THEAD and succeeded:

```
   $thead = $dom_ods->createElement("thead", "");
   $ods2_tmp->insertBefore($thead, $ods2_tmp->firstChild);
   $dom_ods->saveHTML();
```

while I can't for the others, how can I proceed?

Comment: Who says you can't? Did you get an error? Can you show us the attempt?

Comment: Do you mean creating the `<tr>` (using `createElement()`) and the using `appendChild()` to add them into the `$thead`